# Meteor template iterate through array

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    fixtures: function () {
      Meteor.call("checkTwitter", function(error, results) {
        return results.data.fixtures;
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
  Meteor.methods({
        checkTwitter: function () {
            this.unblock();
            var url = "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/73/fixtures";
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", url);
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
<body>
  <h1>Tottenham Hotspur</h1>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <table class="table">
    <th>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Away</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        {{#each fixtures}}
        {{> fixture}}
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

<template name="fixture">
    <td>{{date}}</td>
    <td>{{home}}</td>
    <td>{{result}}</td>
    <td>{{away}}</td>
</template>
```

I am getting a list of fixtures of a football team and returning it as an array 'fixtures'. I could not get my template to list the fixtures. In the console 'resuls.data.fixtures' returns [obj,obj,obj, obj etc...].

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version:

### app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.matches.created = function() {
    this.matches = new ReactiveVar([]);

    var self = this;
    Meteor.call('getMatches', function(error, result) {
      if (result)
        self.matches.set(result);
    });
  };

  Template.matches.helpers({
    matches: function() {
      return Template.instance().matches.get();
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    getMatches: function() {
      var url = "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/73/fixtures";
      try {
        var fixtures = HTTP.get(url).data.fixtures;
        return fixtures;
      } catch (e) {
        return [];
      }
    }
  });
}
```

### app.html

```
<body>
  {{> matches}}
</body>

<template name="matches">
  <h1>Tottenham Hotspur</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <th>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>Away</td>
    </th>
    {{#each matches}}
      <tr>
        {{> match}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>

<template name="match">
  <td>{{date}}</td>
  <td>{{homeTeamName}}</td>
  <td>{{result.goalsHomeTeam}}:{{result.goalsAwayTeam}}</td>
  <td>{{awayTeamName}}</td>
</template>
```

### Notes

- The `fixtures` array was not being parsed out of the original HTTP result, so you were passing extra data (like the headers) back to the client.
- Helpers should be synchronous. Here we use a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) which is asynchronously set when the template is created, but synchronously read in the helper. See my article on [scoped reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) if these techniques are unfamiliar to you.
- The `each` needs to be outside of the `<tr>`.
- Make sure to run: `$ meteor add reactive-var http` for the above example to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the object returned from your **each** loop, which should be `this`, to your **fixture** template:

```
{{#each fixtures}}
  {{> fixture this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: `{{> fixture this}}` should be equivalent to`{{> fixture}}`.